# Use Youtube-dl in python script using import youtube_dl

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, pip, youtube-dl

I want to use youtube-dl in a python script, not using commands. I installed youtube-dl using `pip install youtube-dl` and I also tried installing it using `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl` and also `pip3 install youtube-dl`. It keeps saying I have it installed so I'm guessing the installation is fine.

When I try to use `import youtube_dl` it gives me the error: `unresolved import 'youtube_dl'Python(unresolved-import)`

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a VS Code issue and not a youtube-dl issue. What you need to do is

1. Go into the workspace folder (here workspaceRootFolder) and create a `.env` file
2. In this empty `.env` file add the line `PYTHONPATH=codeFolder` (replace *codeFolder* with your folder name)
3. Add `"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"` to the `settings.json`
4. Restart VS code

Comment: I only have an `index.py` file in my folder. Do I need to add those files you mentioned?

Comment: Create the `.env` file in the root of your project. Where you have the `index.py`

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I have no idea if it is because of your answer or not, but I'm accepting it as answer anyways!